# Pandas sum different before grouping than after

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now.

I have a dataframe with around 3500 rows of raw callcenter data - So each row is a call.

For e.g. say the dataframe only contains three columns: 1) Who made the call, 2) Of which activity the call was a part of and 3) a boolean column with data about whether it was picked up or not.

Instead of saving this entire dataframe I want to group the rows by the activity and the caller and aggregate the two values of the boolean column into two new columns: 'connected calls' and 'not connected calls'.

Everything works fine until I group and aggregate the results where I end up with a lesser number than the total number of rows in the raw dataframe - And I can't  figure out why this happens.

Hope someone out there can help me out :)

This is the part of the code, where I feel something is going wrong. the df-variable is the raw dataframe.

```
connecteds2 = df.filter(['campaigncode', 'user_orgcode', 'connected'])
connecteds2 = pd.concat([connecteds2, pd.get_dummies(df['connected'])], axis=1); connecteds2
del connecteds2['connected']

#Print the total number of rows
print("Rows in dataframe: {}".format(len(connecteds2.index)))

connecteds2 = connecteds2.rename(columns={False: "calls_not_connected", True:"calls_connected"})   
connecteds2 = connecteds2.groupby(['campaigncode', 'user_orgcode']).sum().reset_index()
connecteds2['total_calls'] = connecteds2['calls_not_connected'] + connecteds2['calls_connected']

#Printing sum of total calls across groups
print(connecteds2['total_calls'].sum())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure I understand your issue. The entire point of a `groupby` is to reduce the number of rows - it will reduce rows with the same caller and activity into one single row. Could you share a sample of your expected and actual output to illustrate what you're struggling with?

Comment: Hi Lukas.

Thanks for your comment. 
I'll try to make it a bit more clear, what I'm trying to achieve and where I have issues.
You're totally right. - I'm trying to reduce the rows, as I don't need the raw data, but rather aggregates. 
If I print the total number of rows of the dataframe using len(dataframe.index)) I get a total number of 3545 rows in this example.
After I group the results and sum the number of calls across groups I can a number that's a bit lower - 3421 in this example. 
Does that make it clearer? I've edited the code in the original post to show how I get the sums

Comment: Have you checked if there's rows with no calls made, e.g. `None` in the `connected` column? Such entries will be encoded to `0 0` with `pd.get_dummies` and therefore lower the sum you're seeing after grouping. `df.connected.isna().sum()` should be the difference you're observing, i.e. 124

Comment: That's it! - Or kind of it. I already checked if I had None-values in the connected column, which I hadnt. But apparently I had some in the user_orgcode column, which messed it all up. Thank you all so much. Wouldn't have figured it our without you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the number of rows, probably what you intend is just to add one column with the sum by group. For this case, use the transform function, change the current groupby line for this:

```
import numpy as np
connecteds2["aggregated_sum"] = connecteds2.groupby(
   ['campaigncode', 'user_orgcode']
).transform(np.sum)
```

Transform creates an ouput which is the same size as the input.
Is that what you intended?

For more information, take a look at the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html